# jQuery alert not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

can anybody see where im going wrong here?
Im trying to make a simple alert function when a button is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/jG9SQ/

---

Okay so its working in jsFiddle but not on my website that HAS jQuery running :S

I have the following php...

```
    if($interest1 != ''){
        print $interest1 . "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='deleteinterest'>delete</a><br />";
    }
```

and in my AJAX.JS I have the following...

```
// Delete Interest Function
$(".deleteinterest").click(function()
{        

   alert('hello');
});
// End Delete Interest Function
```

Only this doesnt work?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer by selecting the check mark. It closes the question.

Answer (score 8):

You have mootools selected, try using jquery selection in the jsfiddle menu.

Fixed it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jG9SQ/1/

Comment: Wrong link, you left off the `/1/`